# error when migrating to latest version of Firebase/Firestore dependency

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, dependencies, grpc-java

my app works perfectly fine when using the dependencies with this version as mention 
below, but when migrating to the  latest version of Firestore dependency my app unable to add or delete data in Firestore, I know the lastest dependency don't need firebase-core dependency, though following all the required of firebase mention in official document my app still not working with the latest dependency but working perfectly fine with the dependencies mention below

I want to use the FirestoreUI that's why migrating my project to the latest version, 
I also tried Release Note transitive dependency criteria mention in this website,
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases

but still, show this error, please help me I try all possible things from my side, I hope our StackOverflow family help the newcomer developer

Thank you for your valuable time... happy coding :)

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

repeatedly showing this error(mention below) when adding data to Firestore with latest version,
   `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'`

````
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: CONNECTING
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Setting the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: connectivityAttemptTimer elapsed. Resetting the channel.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Clearing the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: SHUTDOWN
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: stream callback skipped by CloseGuardedRunner.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: IDLE
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Channel successfully reset.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream is open
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream sending: # com.google.firestore.v1.WriteRequest@1f41a322
    database: "projects/notes-2e3bb/databases/(default)"
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: CONNECTING
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Setting the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: connectivityAttemptTimer elapsed. Resetting the channel.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Clearing the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: SHUTDOWN
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [ExponentialBackoff]: Backing off for 0 ms (base delay: 1000 ms, delay with jitter: 509 ms, last attempt: 15181 ms ago)
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: IDLE
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Channel successfully reset.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream is open
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream sending: # com.google.firestore.v1.WriteRequest@1f41a322
database: "projects/notes-2e3bb/databases/(default)"
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: CONNECTING
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Setting the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: connectivityAttemptTimer elapsed. Resetting the channel.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Clearing the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: SHUTDOWN
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [ExponentialBackoff]: Backing off for 0 ms (base delay: 1000 ms, delay with jitter: 509 ms, last attempt: 15181 ms ago)
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: IDLE
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Channel successfully reset.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream is open
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream sending: # com.google.firestore.v1.WriteRequest@1f41a322
    database: "projects/notes-2e3bb/databases/(default)"
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: CONNECTING
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Setting the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: connectivityAttemptTimer elapsed. Resetting the channel.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Clearing the connectivityAttemptTimer
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: SHUTDOWN
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [ExponentialBackoff]: Backing off for 0 ms (base delay: 1500 ms, delay with jitter: 1741 ms, last attempt: 15170 ms ago)
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: IDLE
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Channel successfully reset.
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream is open
I/Firestore: (21.4.1) [WriteStream]: (2b0984f) Stream sending: # com.google.firestore.v1.WriteRequest@1f41a322
```
````